# How to unselect multiple files selected in kivy filechooser List View

Tags: python, user-interface, kivy, filechooser

How can I clear the read only List Property **selection** of the kivy Filechooser or is there any workaround? The thing is that files stay selected even if I return back to my Filechooser window and this is really annoying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even though the **selection** of kivy filechooser is read-only, you can clear selection by just setting selection value to `[]`

Code Example:

```
# import
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen, ScreenManager


class SM(ScreenManager):
    pass


class Screen1(Screen):
    def selected(self, filename):
        # displaying seleted file name as a label
        self.ids.lb.text = str(filename)


class Screen2(Screen):
    def deselect_action(self):
        # access screen1
        s1 = self.manager.get_screen('first')
        # resetting file selection
        s1.ids.select_file.selection = []

# kivy file
kv = Builder.load_string("""
SM:
    Screen1:
    Screen2:

<Screen1>:
    name: 'first'

    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
    
        FileChooserIconView:
            id: select_file
            on_selection: root.selected(select_file.selection)
        Label:
            id: lb
            text: 'default'
        Button:
            text: 'go to second screen'
            on_press: 
                app.root.current = 'second'


<Screen2>:
    name: 'second'

    Button:
        text: 'go back'
        on_press:
            app.root.current = "first"
            root.deselect_action()
""")



class filechoosing(App):
    def build(self):
        return kv

filechoosing().run()
```

Here you can see, the label takes value of the selected file. On returning to the Filechooser window screen, there are no selections.

Answer (score 1):

In order to avoid annoying red points drawned on app screen when clicking on an element, modify the build method that way:

```
def build(self):
    # avoiding red dot put on Kivy screen after mouse right-click
    from kivy import Config
    Config.set('input', 'mouse', 'mouse,disable_multitouch')
    
    return kv
```